# Finding number of points where a given function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]
I was thinking about the above problem.Can someone point me in the right direction?Thanks everyone in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* This function is continuous exactly at the solutions of $\frac{3x}4=\sin x$ (why?)

Comment: @user33640: Note that we have always a sequence of rationals approaching to an irrational number and vice versa.

Comment: @BabakSorouh Thanks a lot sir.I think i have got it.Then there are infinitely many points where the function is continuous.Am i right? Please confirm.

Comment: @user33640: No, see the picture and tell in how many points the two functions intersect each other.

Comment: $\frac{3x}4>1\ge\sin x$ as soon as $x>\frac43$ and $\frac{3x}4<-1\le\sin x$ as soon as $x<-\frac43$. Therefore intersections can occur only in $[-\frac43,\frac43]$.

Comment: @user33640: It was a very kind of you that accepted a very small job I did for you, BUT note that all things we could defeat the problem was completely done by Hagen. So, please accept his. In fact, I didn't nothing but a very small piece here. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh Sir,i have accepted Hagen's solution but how can i algebraically solve the equation $3x/4=sin(x).$ I have tried  it by expanding $sin(x)$ but could not solve.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

They intersect at 3 points each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.I have got it.It is crystal clear now.

Comment: A count of $3$ would be even more crystal clear ...

Comment: Pictures speak more than words, sometimes! +1